# ZURB Foundation 5 change h1, h2, p font-size for small screens only

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm building a responsive website with Foundation 5.4, but I have an issue. I don't know SASS at all, so all changes on color and web fonts I make them by directly changing the `foundation.css` file.

Currently the site is kind of advanced, but I have an issue with `font-size`. I want to change the properties of `p`, `h1`, `h2` and `h3`, but only for small screens as I think they look too big on cellphones. Only I don't know where should I include these properties, or which media query structure to follow.

I know you can do these easily with Ruby or SASS, but I haven't learned these. Also any good material for learning these two is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using SASS at all?

Comment: No I mention that I haven't learned these, so I wanted to know where to write code directly. First time I use any framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS WAY::

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { /*your styles*/}
```

THE SASS WAY:::

In your settings.scss file there is an area for font-size reduction on smaller screens.

It looks like this::

```
// We use these to control header size reduction on small screens
$h1-font-reduction: rem-calc(20) !default;
$h2-font-reduction: rem-calc(10) !default;
$h3-font-reduction: rem-calc(5) !default;
$h4-font-reduction: rem-calc(5) !default;
$h5-font-reduction: 0 !default;
$h6-font-reduction: 0 !default;
```

Also in Foundation you can create custom media queries for small screens only like this:::

```
@media #{$small-only} { }
```

Comment: So I don't need to alter any lines on foundation.css? Could I add these lines on foundation.css or I have to create new css files?

Comment: You should separate your custom css from foundation's